# Reading DAT file via VBA shows spaces between every character

Tags: vba, ms-access, import

I'm getting DAT files filled with measurement values. My idea is to import these files via VBA into an Access Database. I'm still in the very early phase of programming this. I first wanted to make sure I can import a single file. Then move forward to importing batches. What I have so far is:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub TEST_ReadFile()
    Dim fso
    Dim txtstream
    
    Dim hf As Integer: hf = FreeFile
    Dim lines() As String, i As Long
        
    Dim tempLine As String
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim tempLineArray As Variant
    
    Dim sampleGroupID As Integer
    Dim sampleGroupDesc As String
    
    Dim sampleID As Integer
    Dim sampleName As String
    Dim liquid As String
    Dim dateTime As String
    
    Dim valueID As Integer
    Dim time As Date
    Dim base As Double
    Dim height As Double
    Dim volume As Double
    Dim angle As Double
    Dim area As Double
    Dim m_height As Double
    Dim sideArea As Double
        
    
    myFile = "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\N4000289.DAT"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtstream = fso.OpenTextFile(myFile, 1, True)
 
    line = 1
    Do While Not txtstream.AtEndofStream
        tempLine = txtstream.ReadLine()
        If line = 1 Then
            'get data from the header
            tempLineArray = Split(tempLine, vbTab)
            
            If UBound(tempLineArray) - LBound(tempLineArray) + 1 = 3 Then
                sampleName = Replace(Replace(tempLineArray(0), "ÿþ", ""), " ", "")
                'Get rid of strange characters at the start of the file "ÿþ" (working) as well as empty spaces (not working)
                Debug.Print "sampleName: " & sampleName
                
                sampleGroupDesc = Replace(tempLineArray(1), " ", "")
                'Get rid of empty spaces (not working)
                Debug.Print "sampleGroupDesc: " & sampleGroupDesc
                
                liquid = Replace(tempLineArray(2), " ", "")
                'Get rid of empty spaces (not working)
                Debug.Print "liquid: " & liquid
            End If
            
        ElseIf line > 2 Then
            'get the measurement values
        End If


        line = line + 1
    Loop
    txtstream.Close
End Sub
```

The first lines of the .DAT-file read are as following when opening with notepad:

```
N4000289    N. 40g  Ethylene glycol
Time    Base    Height  Volume  Angle   Area    M_Height    SideArea
0,000   0,00    0,00    0,00    0,0 0,00    0,00    0,00
0,010   0,00    0,00    0,00    0,0 0,00    0,00    0,00
0,020   0,00    0,00    0,00    0,0 0,00    0,00    0,00
0,030   2,76    1,15    3,91    77,4    5,99    0,65    2,28
0,040   2,87    1,03    3,80    70,6    6,47    0,59    2,13
```

Importing this file leads to spaces(?) between every single character in the file.
The console shows me the following:

```
sampleName: N 4 0 0 0 2 8 9 
sampleGroupDesc:  N .  4 0 g 
liquid:  E t h y l e n e  g l y c o l
```

Can someone explain to me where these spaces between the characters come from and how I can get rid of them? They also appear in the rest of the file, not just in the first line.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Your file is saved as UTF-16 BE

Answer (score 2):

Try (you possibly have an [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) coded text file)

```
 Set txtstream = fso.OpenTextFile(myFile, 1, True, -1)
```

Further [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method)

You have to make sure you get the file always in the same format.